# use of undeclared identifier 'blockIdx' in cuda

Tags: cuda, clang

I am facing this issue when trying to compile .cu (Cuda) file using clang. Even `threadId.x`  and `blockDim.x` are undeclared.

Can anyone please help with what headers to be included to compile it using clang. 
Compilation using nvcc works fine.

Comment: Use nvcc.  clang doesn't know how to pass device code through the device code compiler.

Comment: Yea. It works with nvcc. I am looking for llvm for my code. Is there any way way to dump the llvm(or nvvm) using nvcc.

Comment: The question you have posed originally is still a duplicate.  You might want to post a new question about dumping llvm from nvcc.  Asking new questions in the comments is not recommended.